# MDL align 'li' text and 'i' icon on one level

Tags: css, material-design

I placed icon inside `<i class="material-icons mdl-color-text">person</i>` but the text in not aligned with the icon.

```
<ul class="mdl-menu mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-menu--bottom-right" for="hdrbtn">
    <li class="mdl-menu__item"><i class="material-icons mdl-color-text">person</i>About</li>
</ul>
```

Is there any build in material css classes that can fix that?

[image]

Comment: you can try to do something like <li><i>person</i><span>About</span></li> And adjust the span in your css